# Trouble with Web Deployment Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made an msi of the web application.When i deploy on the server its working perfectly fine.But for some reason its creating the App_Data folder with two files.i don't know why its getting created automatically ?Did any one face such situation  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably because you have rolemanager enabled in your web.config. That is, it is creating the default membership provider's database. set it to false (or create your own provider) and this will likley not happen

Comment: I agree - just set it to <roleManager enabled="false">

Comment: I did remove the logincontrol which i was using earlier and just used two textboxes and two labels for login and it worked out for me ????